# Kubernetes replicate pod modification to other pods

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

I have a k8s cluster with 3 nodes.
With kubectl command i enter in a pod shell and make some file editing:

```
kubectl exec --stdin --tty <pod-name> -- /bin/bash
```

at this point i have one pod wit correct editing and other 2 replicas with old file.
My question is:
There is a kubectl commend for, starting from a specific pod, overwrite current replicas in cluster for create n equals pods?

Hope to be clear

So many thanks in advance
Manuel

Comment: Hey @Manuel, if the pod is deleted, then again it would be restored back to the original state. So what's the point of making this change manually?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a kubectl plugin called: [kubectl-tmux-exec](https://github.com/predatorray/kubectl-tmux-exec).
All information on how to install and use this plugin can be found on GitHub: [predatorray/kubectl-tmux-exec](https://github.com/predatorray/kubectl-tmux-exec#installation).

As described in the [How to Install Dependencies](https://github.com/predatorray/kubectl-tmux-exec/wiki/How-to-Install-Dependencies) documentation.

> The plugin needs the following programs:
>
> - gnu-getopt(1)
> - tmux(1)

---

I've created a simple example to illustrate you how it works.

Suppose I have a `web` `Deployment` and want to create a `sample-file` file inside all (3) replicas.

```
$ kubectl get deployment,pods --show-labels
NAME                  READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE   LABELS
deployment.apps/web   3/3     3            3           19m   app=web

NAME                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   LABELS
pod/web-96d5df5c8-5gn8x   1/1     Running   0          19m   app=web,pod-template-hash=96d5df5c8
pod/web-96d5df5c8-95r4c   1/1     Running   0          19m   app=web,pod-template-hash=96d5df5c8
pod/web-96d5df5c8-wc9k5   1/1     Running   0          19m   app=web,pod-template-hash=96d5df5c8
```

I have the `kubectl-tmux_exec` plugin installed, so I can use it:

```
$ kubectl plugin list
The following compatible plugins are available:

/usr/local/bin/kubectl-tmux_exec


$ kubectl tmux-exec -l app=web bash
```

After running the above command, Tmux will be opened and we can modify multiple Pods simultaneously:

[image]